# /boot wont take up the unallocated space!

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, gparted, unallocated

I have dual boot on my PC, running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to increase the size of `/boot` so that I can update stuff but apparently boot wont take up the unallocated space directly behind it! I have tried doing it with GParted in Ubuntu and a partition wizard software on Windows. Help please!

Comment: If my answer does not solve your problem, post a link to a gparted screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB and you will be able to extend the partition in gparted.

You cannot extend a partition from inside a working system.

Comment: Yes, you must unmount the partition before you can change the size

Comment: Unmounting `/boot` from within the booted Ubuntu should be enough to get the job done. That said, resizing (especially to the left) is inherently risky, and `/boot` is an extremely important partition. Thus, backing up *before* resizing is important. A file-level backup (using `cp`, `tar`, or the like) should be adequate.